# Enviar datos via Api Rest con un post a un backend en Visual Basic .net MVC

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, postman

No puedo conectar mi servicio Api Rest con un backend hecho en Visual Bacic .net, framework 4.7.2 MVC. 
Puntualmente quiero enviar datos con un post desde Postman a la Api y no puedo recibirlo en los parámetro de la función que llamo.

El inconveniente de esto es que, vis "post", con Postmam, como muestra la foto de abajo. No puedo mandar los datos JSON en el request. Es decir, no llegan al parámetro "data" de la función. 
El problema es que no están llegando los datos JSON que se envían en el raw del body de Postman.

```
 Public Function booking(ByVal data As String) As Boolean

    Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json")

    If Me.RouteData.Values("partnerSupplierId") = "42501" Then

        Dim dataJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data)
        Dim JsonDataRequest As JObject = JObject.Parse(data)

        Dim WebServiceTangolTours As New ServiceReference1.TangolToursClient
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, en lugar de imágenes, copia y pega el código original en la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Listo. Gracias.

Comment: Indica también el error que te da, el tipo, donde ocurre, etc. Cuanta mas información proporciones más fácil será responderte.

Comment: Listo, gracias.

Comment: Una solución parcial que he encontrado es hacer esto:
   
 Public Function booking(ByVal data As Dictionary(Of String, Object), ByVal bookingItems As Dictionary(Of String, Object)) As Boolean

En los parámetros de mi función paso los tipos de datos de Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

La solución era esta:

Tenia que pasar por los parámetros que es donde recibe el objeto JSON el tipo de objeto de los datos se va a recibir. 
En mi caso, creé un clase del tipo del objeto que viene en el JSON.

Public Function booking(ByVal data As **Booking.JsonData**) As String